# Chrome behaving weird with Bootstrap Gradient

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, gradient, bootstrap-5

From one day to another Chrome is suddenly behaving different about the Bootstrap class .bs-gradient
It randomly changes the gradient to color breaks of black, lightblue, darkblue and so on:

[image]

Here's the Code of one of those Boxes:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col clickable">
  <div class="click_left"></div>
  <div class="click_right"></div>
  <div class="card bg-primary bg-gradient">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="stock_item">
        <div class="stock_name row">
          <div class="col">
            T-Shirt Motiv Zirkuskind Blau 140
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="stock_qty row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                                                    <i class="bi bi-dash-lg"></i>
                                                </button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 qtydiv">
            <div class="qtyfield" data-id="">
              10
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
                                                    <i class="bi bi-plus-lg"></i>
                                                </button>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With other Browsers and even on my phone with chrome it works completely normal.

These are the properties that Bootstrap 5 gives to the classes "bs-primary", "bs-gradient" and "card":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I turned off Hardware Accelaration in Chrome. Now it works without any glitching.